# Сохранение текста поискового запроса после возвращения из фрагмента

Tags: android, android-studio, listview, android-fragment, backstack

В приложении есть несколько фрагментов. В одном из них есть `ListView`, для поиска по которому используется `SearchView`. При нажатии на элемент списка с помощью метода `replace` отображается страница этого элемента, вызванный фрагмент добавляется в `backStack`. Как организовать сохранение текста поискового запроса при возвращении со страницы элемента обратно в список всех элементов? То есть при переходе на страницу элемента и возвращении обратно поисковый запрос не должен пропадать. В приложении есть возможность отследить, с какого фрагмента совершен переход во фрагмент со списком, так что можно опираться на это.

Инициализация SearchView

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_recipes, menu);
    mMenu = menu;
    //создание поисковой строки в ActionBar
    MenuItem menuItemSearch = mMenu.findItem(R.id.recipes_search);
    searchView = (SearchView) menuItemSearch.getActionView();
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) context.getSystemService(SEARCH_SERVICE);
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getActivity().getComponentName()));
    searchView.setQueryHint(getString(R.string.hint_what_are_you_looking_for));
    searchView.setId(View.generateViewId());
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) { //нажатие на кнопку поиска на клавиатуре
            //скрыть клавиатуру
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(null, InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) { //изменение текста в строке поиска
            Search search = new Search();
            search.RecipesSearch(context, newText, allRecipes, lviRecipes);
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Сохранение и получения состояния

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putString("search query", searchView.getQuery().toString());
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null && savedInstanceState.get("search query") != null)
        searchView.setQuery(savedInstanceState.get("search query").toString(), true);
}
```

Comment: Должен ли  `listView` сохранять прокрутку?

Comment: @timuruktus сохранение прокрутки уже реализовано

Comment: Не знаю, пока единственное, что приходит в голову- сохранение строчки поиска через SharedPreferences в onPause() и получение в onResume()

Answer (score 0):

У SearchView есть id? Если есть id то по дефолту состояние сохраняется.

Comment: можно ли задать id программно? SearchView создается именно таким способом

Comment: SearchView searchView = new SearchView(getActivity());
        searchView.setId();

Comment: SearchView не такой просто элемент, в Bundle стандартным инструментом не сохраняется состояние, более того SearchView меняет свое представление в LandScape ориентации, что приводит к определенным багам в состояниях. 
Но вы частично правы, для того чтоб начал работать стандартный инструмент нужно устанавливать id.

Comment: @EugeneZaychenko Как при помощи setId я могу задать ID, если на вход он принимает значение ID типа int, которого нет в программе? Пробовал задать ID через searchView.generateViewId(); и searchView.setId(View.generateViewId());, но сохранения состояния не происходит

Comment: @EugeneZaychenko добавил код в вопрос

Answer (score 0):

Вопросы по сохранению состояния всегда больны, вроде бы Google имеет инструмент  `onSaveInstanceState()` что пишет в Bundle, а вроде возникают множество ситуаций когда он железно не работает.

Так вот я настоятельно не рекомендую на данный момент использовать стандартный инструмент (`onRestoreInstanceState()`) для SearchView, так как там есть багв в Callbacks именно в сохранении состоянии, который лечится очень плохим способом.

Я рекомендую для данного элемента хранить состояние в отдельном месте, зависит от организации структуру. Хороший тон на данный момент имея например MVP иметь прослойку ViewState, которая отвечает именно за это, это будет что-то вроде кеша состояния, который решает все проблемы.

Также вам советовали использовать SharedPreference, я считаю это хороший совет, если у вас нет организованной структуру в приложении, это будет самый быстрый и эффективный способ. Вам необходимо в ручную менеджить состояние. 
Вы можете например в onResume восстанавливать, и в onPause сохранять в Preference.